# SSIS 2008 package does not open in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis-2008

I have an SSIS package that was created in SSIS 2008 (as confirmed by inspecting the 'PackageFormatVersion' property in the package.dtsx XML file).  I am trying to open (and run) this package in Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Integrated).  This instance of Visual Studio only has SQL Server Data Tools 14.0.61705.170 installed.  When I try to open the package, I get the message "this version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects..."  How do I resolve this?